# Word splitting in TextView

Tags: android, textview

I'm using TextView to show some messages in my app. The messages contains some HTML tags so I'm using `textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(message))`. But there is an issue with this. Concrete words  splitting in to two lines as shown below.

[image]

I need the words to not split and behave like it does with `textView.setText(message)`.

TextView definition:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:padding="@dimen/padding"

    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginTop"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/marginBottom"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/marginRight"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:shadowColor="@color/textShadow"
    android:shadowDx="1"
    android:shadowDy="1"
    android:text="msg"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textColorLink="@android:color/black"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:textSize="@dimen/textSize" />
```

Comment: Try Html.fromHtml(message).toString() and see whether it helps.

Comment: @Egor Nops, it's not helping.

Comment: Please show how you are defining the `TextView`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I added TextView definition.

Comment: have you don't allow to show new line in your textview?

Comment: @Haresh What I need is that if mentioned scenario occurs, the full word 'everything' should go to new line rather than just a few characters of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are intentionally telling Android to not split across words, by using a non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`). Replace those with actual spaces.

Comment: Android's  `Html` control does not handles actual spaces. If there are multiple spaces, they will not be considered for drawing text on textView.

Comment: @Ammar: So? According to [your other comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24431494/word-spliting-in-textview/24433302?noredirect=1#comment37801480_24431895), you are not using multiple spaces. You have only one `&nbsp;` entity in between the words. If you want breaking spaces, **use regular spaces**, not non-breaking spaces.

Comment: The mentioned comment contains just an example. The text may contain multiple spaces, as there is no restriction needed.

Comment: @Ammar: Then convert **all but one** of them into `&nbsp;` per sequence. Leave a single space alone. Change a sequence of two spaces into a single space and `&nbsp;`. Change a sequence of three spaces into a single space and `&nbsp;&nbsp;`. And so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

is the property of textview and edittext which will keep the text on single line. if length of string is too big then text will be truncated but will never go on next line.

If possible can you pl add your message value i.e. the html you are passing to Html.fromHtml.

Comment: Can't use android:singleLine="true" as my text can be multiline. For the gives image, I'm passing 'ho&nbsp;is&nbsp;going&nbsp;everything&nbsp;guys' for the given image.